# If I use node_save() to create a new node, do I need to manually escape user input?

Tags: 6, security

I am writing a custom module for Drupal 6 that programmatically creates a node using node_save().

The various custom node fields come from user input - is it necessary to manually escape these fields, or will node_save() take care of that for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by escaping you mean using `check_plain()` or similar functions, then no; escaping is done when outputting something, not when saving it in the database, or in Drupal persistent variables.

Imagine what would happen if you call `check_plain()` on a node containing "&"; that character would be escaped to "`&amp;`" that it would be converted in `&amp;amp;` when Drupal would show the node content. The result is that "&" would be shown as "&amp;" and that is not what it would be expected.

In [Writing secure code](http://drupal.org/writing-secure-code), you can read the following text:

> Use check functions on output to prevent cross site scripting attacks
>
> No piece of user-submitted content should ever be placed as-is into HTML.
>
> - Use `check_plain()` or `theme('placeholder')` for plain text.
> - Use `check_markup()` or `filter_xss()` for markup containing text.
> - Use the `t()` function with "@" or "%" placeholders to construct safe, translatable strings.
>
> See [how to handle text in a secure fashion](http://drupal.org/node/28984) for more details.

As you see, the page about writing secure code doesn't say to escape the text being saved, but only text being output, when the text has been entered from users, in a way or in another. An example of text entered from a user is the username or the signature associated to user accounts, the node title, or the node body.

About SQL injection, you just need to use placeholders in you queries; Drupal database functions escapes the content of the placeholders, which would not be possible if you write a query like the following one, for example:

```
$query = db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE title = '$title'");
```

The "Writing secure code" reports:

> Use the database layer correctly. For example, never concatenate data directly into SQL queries, like this:
>
> ```
> <?php
>  db_query('SELECT foo FROM {table} t WHERE t.name = '. $_GET['user']); 
> ?>
> ```
>
> Instead, use proper argument substitution with db_query:
>
> ```
> <?php
>  db_query("SELECT foo FROM {table} t WHERE t.name = '%s' ", $_GET['user']); 
> ?>
> ```
>
> If you have to accommodate a variable number of arguments in your SQL, create an array of placeholders. Don't do this:
>
> ```
> <?php
>  db_query("SELECT t.s FROM {table} t WHERE t.field IN (%s)", $from_user); 
> ?>
> ```
>
> Instead, do this:
>
> ```
> <?php
>  $placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($from_user), "%d"));
>  db_query("SELECT t.s FROM {table} t WHERE t.field IN ($placeholders)", $from_user); 
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified - I was talking about SQL injection. I will strip html tags when outputting it too.

Comment: The page on writing secure code doesn't, but the next page in the series does: http://drupal.org/node/101495 (handling user input with care)

Comment: That's the thing. I understand that using placeholders within db_query removes the risk, but I'm not using db_query - I'm using node_save(). Thanks for your answer, by the way :)

Comment: @John McCollum Yet, it's not about escaping the input of the user before saving it. The database API takes care of escaping the values, but the saved values are still what the user entered.

Comment: `node_save()` doesn't need to escape the values because its code has been written following the points on how to write secure code. It's the database API that takes care of any security issues for SQL injection, and other problems; `node_save()` doesn't need to do anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly glanced through [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6) and there is no escaping done on the $node object before [drupal_write_record](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6), drupal_write_record does no escaping either so even if I've overlooked something your best bet is to escape. Better safe than sorry!